# Is there any fixed size of the webpage?

Tags: html4

I have started HTML. I am making tables in it. I just tried breaking the webpage into two by adding a sidebar at the left but I am confused with its size. What is the standard size of a webpage? Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Inter Notes Homepage</title>
    </head>

    <body>
<table>
            <tr height="50">
                <td width="200" height="610"></td>
                <td width="800" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You also [should not be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) using tables for layout.

Comment: Thanks. I would try to use div's from now on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard size to a webiste as such as it will vary according to the screen size of the user.  You can generally do one of two things.  You can work in % based measurements, where the tables sizes can be set to stretch the full browser size for example as 100%, or any other size for that matter.
The alternative is to use fixed widths such as pixels.  Generally, we design sites to fit a 1024x768 screen resolution as a minimum.  This roughly translates into 950px or 960px wide.

All depends on the design of the site as to which is a better option for you.  I am more a fan of fixed width designs.

Comment: Depends... i would think most would be % based. But each will vary i suppose.